# Magento 2 admin menu extension

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid-layout

What is the proper way to e.g: get Sitemap generation grid to load on custom route? Currently on custom route the grid layout won't be rendered, all I see is "Popular Site Map" title which comes from my:

```
Product\Sitemap\Controller\Adminhtml\PopularSitemap;
/**
 * Index action
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function execute()
{
    $this->_initAction();
    $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Popular Site Map'));
    $this->_view->renderLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The mistake was very small and stupid :), reference container block was refencing, non exsistant block->

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Product\Sitemap\Block\Adminhtml\Sitemap"
name="adminhtml.popular.sitemap.container"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

It should be->

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Product\Sitemap\Block\Adminhtml\PopularSitemap" name="adminhtml.popular.sitemap.container"/>
</referenceContainer>
```